# Generate shareable link feature in Django?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework application that is fed in data from a csv. I then use React to create dashboards and Widgets from that data. I want to be able to generate a link to share a read-only version of any dashboard, much like in Google docs etc. Anyone clicking on that link will be able to see the dashboard with all the charts and analytics etc. The link can be shared much like how you share a Google Forms link. I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any help / pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What I understood from your question: 'You want a link builder' and 'You want the api to be read Only'. Is that right?

Comment: @yousof  I'm not sure what is meant by a 'link builder'. But I want to share a particular dashboard through a link unique to that dashboard or a widget. Anyone who clicks on that link should be able to view that dashboard. It's not the same as sharing the URL of the page, as the page may have multiple widgets. Also the page / dashboard belongs to a particular user, so sharing the URL of the page will obviously require authentication etc. Sharing link generated for the particular dashboard will not require authentication. Anyone with the link can access.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think theoretically you need to use a router on your react app (e.g. https://reactrouter.com/ ).

If you're using create-react-app, you can also refer to [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-router/#:~:text=Create%20React%20App%20doesn't,is%20the%20most%20popular%20one.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-router/#:%7E:text=Create%20React%20App%20doesn%27t,is%20the%20most%20popular%20one.)) .

With this you can directly read parameters on a certain page within your react app, that you can then use to build a concrete call to the backend, to retrieve the necessary data to build your dashboard.

The 'link builder' functionality most likely needs to be implemented on the backend, so you can have the necessary parameters you need to gather the necessary data, maybe by using query strings.

If you want to make it more complex, you would need to implement on the backend a kind of tokenized access, that could store the full call parameters on the backend side, and associate them with a token of some kind, that you could then provide to your clients.

e.g. : `http://djangoappxpto.com/link/12345abcd` points to a react page component that then executes a `fetch` to `http://djangoappxpto.com/api/getStats/12345abcd` which once received by python would internally mean something like `http://djangoappxpto.com/api/generateStatsReport/?param1=a&param2=b&param3=w&param4=aa` .

Comment: Thanks Telmo Dias. Let me go back and try that and learn more about it before I get back. Thank you for your time and suggestion!